# вывод в context ListView

Tags: python, django

имеется view в данном виде:

```
def group_posts(request, slug):
    """Страница сообществ."""
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=slug)
    post_queryset = group.posts.all()

    page_obj = paginator(post_queryset, POST_PER_PAGE, request)
    context = {'group': group, 'page_obj': page_obj, }
    return render(request, 'posts/group_list.html', context)
```

Я хочу переделать его в class ListView. Получился такой вариант.

```
class Group_posts(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "posts/group_list.html"
    paginate_by = POST_PER_PAGE

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = str(context['page_obj'][0].group)
        context['description'] = str(context['page_obj'][0].group.description)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(group__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

у меня не получилось вывести group в context, а только через get_context_data атрибуты group. возможно ли вывести group в context целиком?

Comment: вот стоило задать вопрос, и сам тут же нашел ответ. context['group'] = Group.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

Comment: Но буду признателен за более оптимизированный вариант.